# Couldn't find model without an ID (rails4 with strong parameters)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, belongs-to, strong-parameters

I have 2 models user and order

in the user model i have the following

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 include ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection

 has_many orders
end
```

in the orders model, i have

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
 include ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection

 belongs_to user
end
```

in the orders controller i have

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
 before_action :set_order, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

 def create   
@user = User.find(params[:user_id])     
@order = @user.orders.build(order_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @order.save
    format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @order }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @orders.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

  private

  def order_params    
    params[:order].permit( :order_title, :propose_amount, 
     :terms,:users_attributes =>  [:user_id]) 
  end

end
```

on creating the order, i keep getting the error below

```
    Couldn't find user without an ID
```

and the following line is higlighted as the line of error

```
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
```

does anyone knows where am heading wrong?

Comment: Your `params[:user_id]` is `nil`. Have you make `orders` a nested resource of `users` in your `routes.rb`? Also, you won't have `users_attributes`. Either way I think usually user would come from the current user session not from the params otherwise you will have  problem where people can make orders for other people.

Comment: i made my routes as `resource users do orders end`

Comment: `resources users do resources orders end`

Comment: I have made that change, but still the problem persists.

Comment: what's in your `orders#new`? if you are creating your form with `form_for` you could do something like `form_for([@user, @user.orders.build])`… In any case, Rails has pretty good documentation so please read the doc: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: can you Please post the `development.log parameters` after submitting your `form`.